# CS50 | SQL - Not sure why only "Kevin bacon" is being printed

Tags: sqlite, cs50

I think below query should print out the names of all the people who have starred in a movie in which Kevin Bacon has starred.

However, it is only printing out "Kevin Bacon" multiple times. Any help?

```
SELECT name 
FROM people 
JOIN stars ON people.id = stars.person_id 
JOIN movies ON movies.id = stars.movie_id 
WHERE movies.id IN (SELECT id FROM movies WHERE name = "Kevin Bacon" AND birth = 1958);
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that in the table `movies` there are columns `name` and `birth`, so in this query:

```
SELECT id FROM movies WHERE name = "Kevin Bacon" AND birth = 1958
```

the columns `name` and `birth` refer to the table `people`.

For this requirement you must join `people` and `stars` twice like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p2.name 
FROM people p1 
INNER JOIN stars s1 ON s1.person_id = p1.id 
INNER JOIN movies m ON m.id = s1.movie_id 
INNER JOIN stars s2 ON s2.movie_id = m.id
INNER JOIN people p2 ON p2.id = s2.person_id 
WHERE p1.name = 'Kevin Bacon' and p2.name <> 'Kevin Bacon';
```